# Ruby PATH is not correctly set up

Tags: ruby, rvm

OK so I had Ruby working perfectly to use guard to watch some sass files, I restarted my computer, apple did some updates (no idea if this is related to the problem or not). Once it had rebooted, I went to switch guard back on, and I get this error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/ImageMagick/bin in PATH, mode 040757
```

Now the one thing that is pretty obvious is the 'Imagemagick' in the middle of my path, I have no idea how that got there, and fairly sure thats my problem.

When I try and run most things in Ruby I get this :

```
PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin' is not available,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448'.
```

`rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` doesnt seem to do anything for me. Running `rvm info` gives me this for the path:

```
    PATH:         "/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/ImageMagick/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/bin"
```

Just want to know how I can fix this path or anything that will sort my problems, I feel like I've been going round in circles for too long now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on OSX Mavericks. The solution that worked for me was to add the rvm path to the `PATH` environment variable in ~/.bash_profile file. In my case, I did not have a system wide installation of rvm, so the following entry worked for me.

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

there is something resetting the `PATH` set by rvm, search your shell initialization files for `PATH=` not containing `$PATH`.

Comment: Hey, sorry, im not too hot on ruby, how and where can i do this?

Comment: it is not ruby it is your shell, and shell initialization files means all the files loaded when shell is started, like `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` and similar files in `/etc`