# Git rebase error: This application will not run on your computer

Tags: macos, git, emacs, rebase

I'm trying to change my commit message using

> git rebase -i HEAD~2

But when I do it i got a window with a message `This application will not run on your computer. Sorry!`

At terminal I have:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/
 usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: 
 warning: Insecure world writable dir /Volumes/SSS/Work in PATH, mode 040777
button returned:OK
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

I have OSX 10.9. What is wrong with it?

---

More info:

1. git version 1.7.11.3
2. I should not have hooks. But may be I miss something. (I checked ~/.gitconfig)
3. When I change core.editor from emacs to nano the error disappear. So the problem seems to be emacs-related.

Comment: Since you're using `rebase -i`, perhaps it's your configured editor that's causing issues? What does `git config --get core.editor` return?

Comment: It is related to Emacs, see [this piece of code](https://github.com/caldwell/build-emacs/blob/master/launch.rb) which contains the error you're getting. Don't know how to solve this though, not an Emacs nor a Ruby expert :)

Comment: Yes. I changed to nano and this helped.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/19758050/6309 help?

Comment: If you are using Emacs (I can't see this from your post), then why not use `magit`? It has interactive rebase feature. Maybe Git doesn't know how to find Emacs and that's why it complains? Still I'd not use Emacs that way, and if anything, I'd try to use `emacsclient` for it.

Comment: @wvxvw, I would like to stay in terminal.

Comment: Erm... just run Emacs `-nw` then? Sorry, I don't quite understand the problem.

Comment: @wvxvw, problem is described in the question: "This application will not run on your computer. Sorry!"

Comment: Oh, I see now, well, that's some Ruby script that generates the error. What I meant by my previous comment is that you would still be in terminal when using `magit`, it doesn't have to be one or the other.

Comment: Aha, I see now too:). I can run emacs-nw in terminal and just to use magit. I shell try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I use alias `emacs` for MacOS's `Emacs`. It was solved by changing:

> editor = emacs -nw

to

> editor = Emacs -nw

in `~/.gitconfig`